# Why Xcode not getting GADApplicationIdentifier from info.plist which is used for Google Mobile Ad SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, google-mobile-ads

I'm asking this question after trying all possible ways to solve the issues I'm facing. First, let's see the error and I will tell what I have done to solve it but unfortunately, nothing is really working for me.

So, I have imported the Google Mobile AD sdk using cocoaPod. Added the following line in AppDelegate:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
```

and the following in info.plist:

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
<key>GADIsAdManagerApp</key>
<true/>
```

However, the app keeps on throwing the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to set GADApplicationIdentifier with a valid app ID. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist'
```

I tried to import Firebase but still could not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hhave you tried, removing the `GADApplicationIdentifier` key and its value inside info.plit, then trying it out then re-adding it, and trying it out again.

Comment: Yup. but unfortunately, the problem is not resolved.

Comment: @Omar did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What I did was that I created a whole new project and copied all the codes to it. Then it worked. seems like there was a problem in the project file itself. I hope this will help.